# Symmetrize armature is missing bones

Tags: armature

Symmetrize is missing some of my fingers bones, i try it several times but it just won't work and i have no idea why
[image]

Comment: do their names have the good suffix, like ".R" or "_R"? otherwise it can't symmetriz

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your bones a suffix *L* (for left) or *R* (for right) if you want them to be symmetrized, example: *finger1.R*, *finger1_R*...